# Need help in Syntax for accessing data in JSP

Tags: database, oracle, jsp

I need to access data from a table. I have used the code like this:

```
string sql = "select * from bikesold "
           + "where model = '"+model+"'
           + "and mnth = '"+mnth+"' ";
```

The error is coming as follows:
ORA-00904: "MNTH": invalid identifier.

All the database connections are ok. I just need to confirm the Syntax for this code.

Comment: Is your code compilable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sql = "select * from bikesold "
           + "where model = '"+model+"'"
           + "and mnth = '"+mnth+"' ";
```

you have missed the double quote in 2nd string.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your string is wrong.  Try this instead:

```
string sql = "select * from bikesold "
           + "where model = '"+ model +
           + "' and mnth = '"+ mnt + "'";
```

Q: Does your table actually have a column named "mnth'?

Comment: Yes it does. By the way, the first answer worked. There was a mistake with the double quotes. Thanks.:)

Comment: The mistake with the double quotes was what I meant by "the string is wrong".  Had you looked at the response (or simply tried copy/paste into your code), you would have seen that a couple of days ago :)